# jdbc java.sql.preparedstatement duplicating rows during insert

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, ojdbc

I have a program in scala that connects to an oracle database using ojdbc, queries a table, and tries to insert records from the java.sql.resultSet into another table on a separate jdbc connection.

```
//conn1 to oracle: java.sql.Connection = oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@698122b2
//conn2 to another non-oracle database: java.sql.Connection = com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1@6e4566f1
```

My attempt at capturing results from an oracle table:

```
val stmt1 = conn1.createStatement()
stmt1.setFetchSize(3000)
val sql1 = "select userid from nex.users"
val result = stmt1.executeQuery(sql1)
```

and code for attempting to insert records from result to a separate database and table via jdbc:

```
val insert_sql = "insert into test.users (userid) values (?)"
val ps = conn2.prepareStatement(insert_sql)
val batchSize = 3000
var count = 0
while (result.next) {
    ps.setInt(1, result.getInt(1))
    ps.addBatch()
    count += 1
    if (count % batchSize == 0) ps.executeBatch()
}
```

What's stumping me is this is almost the exact same syntax in many examples of using jdbc, but in my second table, I'm seeing 4x the original number of rows from the first table.

```
select userid, count(*) from test.users group by userid


1 4
2 4
3 4
4 4
5 4
6 4
etc
```

Comment: Are you sure the `test.users` table was empty prior to running your code?

Comment: yes, I'm truncating the table anytime I try something new with the code and making sure there are 0 rows

Comment: sorry to ask the obvious, but if you were to run `select userid, count(*) from nex.users group by userid`, are the user IDs unique in that table?

Comment: Hi hsl, yep the userids were unique. I got a suggestion from a colleague - please see answer below

Answer (score 1):

Yes, clearBatch is missing.

*executeBatch() calls clearBatch() in the end.
But there is no guarantee for that will be exactly the same in other implementations.*

Also, if needed, I am making a minor-subtle addition to tchoedak's  answer :)

```
ps.executeBatch();
conn2.commit();
ps.clearBatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to execute `ps.clearBatch()` after every execute, otherwise the next batch would get piled on top of the previous batch. When trying this on a large table that would need to call executeBatch more often, the amount of duplicate rows were x times higher. The final code looks similar but with `ps.clearBatch()` .

```
val ps = conn2.prepareStatement(insert_sql)
val batchSize = 3000
var count = 0
while (result.next) {
    ps.setInt(1, result.getInt(1))
    ps.addBatch()
    count += 1
    if (count % batchSize == 0) 
        ps.executeBatch()
        ps.clearBatch()
}
```